# Create a rectangle using two points

Tags: vectors, rectangles

First of all, i'm new here, sorry if i miss anything, speak and draw badly.

I have 2 vectors and the length $n$, I want to know the formula to get corners of [this **equilateral** rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8aQfm.png).

[image]
([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8aQf.png))

I'm working on a C# program if you really want to know, but I think this is overall more related to maths. I hope the picture is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference vector $d$ between the red points $P=(p_x, p_y)$ and $Q =(q_x, q_y)$ is
$$
d = P - Q = (p_x - q_x, p_y - q_y)
$$
The two vectors $n$ fulfill $n \perp d$ thus
$$
0 = n \cdot d = n_x d_x + n_y d_y \quad (*)
$$
and have the length 
$$
\lVert n \rVert = \sqrt{n^2} = \sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2} \quad (**)
$$
The  green points then are $P + n$ and $Q + n$.

To determine $n$ we have two unknowns $n_x$ and $n_y$ and two equations $(*)$ (a line) and $(**)$ (a circle) so there might be zero (line and circle do not intersect), one or two solutions.

Assuming $d \ne 0$ ($P$ and $Q$ are not equal), we have either $d_x$ or $d_y$ not zero. We assume $d_y \ne 0$ (otherwise $d_x \ne 0$ and the following can be performed with $x$ and $y$ coordinates swapped). Then
$$
n_y = -\frac{d_x}{d_y} n_x \quad (***)
$$
and we can write
$$
\lVert n \rVert^2
=n_x^2 + n_y^2 
= \left( 1 + \left(\frac{d_x}{d_y} \right)^2 \right) n_x^2 
$$
which gives
$$
n_x 
= \pm \frac{\lVert n \rVert}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{d_x}{d_y} \right)^2 }}
$$
So you can determine $n_x$ from $d$ and $\lVert n \rVert$ and use $(***)$ to get $n_y$.

Remember to check the assumptions in your program. If $d = 0$ then there is no unique solution. If $d_y = 0$ you need to do the above swapped. In case of $\lVert n \rVert = 0$ you will just get one solution, the original $P$ and $Q$.